# In android, onActivityResult method how can i know which button is clicked "Save" or "Cancel" button after calling Calender event through intent

Tags: android-intent

I have called an inbuilt Calender Event from an Activity,on executing my code it is redirecting me to device calender from my activity, but i want to redirect to two different activities on save and cancel button clicks of that device calender. But how can i know whether user pressed "Save" button  or "Cancel" button in the device calender in my "onActivityResult" method.

Please can i get the solution for this???